# CLASSPATH java

Tags: windows, cmd, java

Хочу уточнить.

Долго не мог собрать проект, в итоге возникло такое подозрение:
Если я явно в команде `javac` или `java` укажу пути `-classpath`, тогда будут игнорироваться пути, прописанные в переменной среды CLASSPATH?!

Как я ожидал, то, что прописано в `-classpath`, добавится к тому, что прописано в CLASSPATH. Сейчас сомневаюсь...

Comment: [зубри это](http://skipy.ru/technics/likbez.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CLASSPATH` - это переменная окружения, которая применяется ко всем командам JDK. Если значение переменной `CLASSPATH`, то по умолчание оно равно `.`.

Ключи `-classpath` или `-cp` предназанчены для тонкого управления путями к библиотекам, переопредеяют значение переменной `CLASSPATH` и являются рекомендованным способом управления путями.